# Javascript (jQuery) two select price from/to ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select form fields. One is the "price_from", the other is "price_to". The problem is that I want to prevent the user for selecting for example price_from "10000" and price_to "1000", so basically I must find some javascript function which sets the "price_to" field values based on "price_to" values onwards. ie : If I select the price_from ="3000", the price_from field will display values from "4000". And ofcourse vice-versa. If somebody changes the "price_to" or "price_from" field again.

Comment: And what HTML are you working with? Can you post a demo with what you've already got at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar..? And, rather than two linked sliders, would it not be easier to use one range-slider?

Comment: I'm working in an example. Wait a moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="from1" relatedTo="to1">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
</select>

<select id="to1" relatedTo="from1">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
</select>

<br/>

<select id="from2" relatedTo="to2">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
</select>

<select id="to2" relatedTo="from2">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// function to valide two selects
function validateSelects( fromSelector, toSelector ) {

    // registering the change event to the "to" select
    $( toSelector ).change(function() {

        var fromSelector = "#" + $(this).attr( "relatedTo" );
        var toSelector = "#" + $(this).attr( "id" );

        // compares the value of the selected item with the from select
        if ( $(this).val() > $( fromSelector ).val() ) {

            // selects the value of the from select
            $(this).val( $( fromSelector ).val() );

        }

    });

    // puts the gui in a valid state
    $( fromSelector ).change(function() {

        var fromSelector = "#" + $(this).attr( "id" );
        var toSelector = "#" + $(this).attr( "relatedTo" );

        // compares if the value of this field is less than the value of the "to" select
        if ( $(this).val() < $( toSelector ).val() ) {

            // if so, change the value of the "to" select
            $( toSelector ).val( $(this).val() );

        }

    });

}

validateSelects( "#from1", "#to1" );
validateSelects( "#from2", "#to2" );
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/YNL6R/

**Edit:** I inserted a custom atribute in each select to denote the select that they are binded.

Comment: thank you but it's not working properly. And it's really strange :). For example if you select price from "10000" and select price to "9000" it's ok, but if you select price to "1000" its not :).. Try with my loop in next answer

Comment: It is because the way that I wrote the code. If you are trying to do this with two or more couples of fields, you will have problems... I'm updating my solution.

Comment: @Grunje_D_D: take a look. I updated my code, creating a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

And this is the html code . @davidbuzatto your code is working, but try to select price_from 10000 and price to 1000 you will see.

```
<select name="pricesFrom" id="pricefrom"><option value="0" selected>Any</option><option value="500">500.00</option><option value="1000">1,000.00</option><option value="2000">2,000.00</option><option value="3000">3,000.00</option><option value="4000">4,000.00</option><option value="5000">5,000.00</option><option value="6000">6,000.00</option><option value="7000">7,000.00</option><option value="8000">8,000.00</option><option value="9000">9,000.00</option><option value="10000">10,000.00</option><option value="11000">11,000.00</option><option value="12000">12,000.00</option><option value="13000">13,000.00</option><option value="14000">14,000.00</option><option value="15000">15,000.00</option><option value="16000">16,000.00</option><option value="17000">17,000.00</option><option value="18000">18,000.00</option><option value="19000">19,000.00</option><option value="20000">20,000.00</option></select></label><label>Price to
                        <select name="pricesTo" id="priceto"><option value="0" selected>Any</option><option value="500">500.00</option><option value="1000">1,000.00</option><option value="2000">2,000.00</option><option value="3000">3,000.00</option><option value="4000">4,000.00</option><option value="5000">5,000.00</option><option value="6000">6,000.00</option><option value="7000">7,000.00</option><option value="8000">8,000.00</option><option value="9000">9,000.00</option><option value="10000">10,000.00</option><option value="11000">11,000.00</option><option value="12000">12,000.00</option><option value="13000">13,000.00</option><option value="14000">14,000.00</option><option value="15000">15,000.00</option><option value="16000">16,000.00</option><option value="17000">17,000.00</option><option value="18000">18,000.00</option><option value="19000">19,000.00</option><option value="20000">20,000.00</option></select>
```

Comment: Try my changed code. When you have new content to your question, just update the original one ok? The comments are used to discuss briefly, not to complement the question ;)